# Scala - Not enough arguments for method count

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am fairly new to Scala and Spark RDD programming. The dataset I am working with is a CSV file containing list of movies (one row per movie) and their associated user ratings (comma delimited list of ratings). Each column in the CSV represents a distinct user and what rating he/she gave the movie. Thus, user 1's ratings for each movie are represented in the 2nd column from the left:

Sample Input:

Spiderman,1,2,,3,3

Dr.Sleep, 4,4,,,1

I am getting the following error:

```
Task4.scala:18: error: not enough arguments for method count: (p: ((Int, Int)) => Boolean)Int.
Unspecified value parameter p.
    var moviePairCounts = movieRatings.reduce((movieRating1, movieRating2) => (movieRating1, movieRating2, movieRating1._2.intersect(movieRating2._2).count()
```

when I execute the few lines below. For the program below, the second line of code splits all values delimited by "," and produces this:

( Spiderman, [[1,0],[2,1],[-1,2],[3,3],[3,4]] )
( Dr.Sleep, [[4,0],[4,1],[-1,2],[-1,3],[1,4]] )

On the third line, taking the count() throws an error. For each movie (row), I am trying to get the number of common elements. In the above example, [-1, 2] is clearly a common element shared by both Spiderman and Dr.Sleep.

```
    val textFile = sc.textFile(args(0))
    
    var movieRatings = textFile.map(line => line.split(","))
                                .map(movingRatingList => (movingRatingList(0), movingRatingList.drop(1)
                                .map(ranking => if (ranking.isEmpty) -1 else ranking.toInt).zipWithIndex));
                                

    
    var moviePairCounts = movieRatings.reduce((movieRating1, movieRating2) => (movieRating1, movieRating2, movieRating1._2.intersect(movieRating2._2).count() )).saveAsTextFile(args(1));
```

My target output of line 3 is as follows:

( Spiderman, Dr.Sleep, 1 ) --> Between these 2 movies, there is 1 common entry.

Can somebody please advise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the number of elements in a collection, use `length` or `size`. `count()` returns number of elements which satisfy some additional condition.

Or you could avoid building the complete intersection by using `count` to count the elements of the first collection which the second contains:

```
movieRating1._2.count(movieRating2._2.contains(_))
```

Comment: Okay, I think I mistook count [the Scala function] for the Spark RDD Action, count. I intended to use the RDD action, Count. I am frequently mistakening Scala functions for Spark RDD Actions. How could I easily tell which one will be applied (ie. is the only way to know this to explicitly print out the value of the variable to the console, and if it's Spark.RDD type, then I know the RDD Action will be invoked, but if it's a non-RDD type, then I can assume it's the Scala method that's applied ?

Comment: Also, if I want to speed up my program, I should be using RDD Transforms/Actions as much as possible as opposed to using the regular Scala methods, right ? Because the RDD Transforms/Actions cause the data to be processed in a distributed manner, whereas using Scala methods causes data to be run on a single machine + single thread, is my understanding correct ?

Comment: 1. RDD transforms and actions _are_ Scala methods. They are just not Scala collection methods. 2. Instead of printing values I'd suggest putting type annotations, e.g. `val movieRatings: RDD[...]`. In an IDE just hovering over the variable should show you the type. 3. "whereas using Scala methods causes data to be run on a single machine + single thread" Not if you use them inside a lambda passed to an RDD method...

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear: `count` takes one argument, but in your call, you are passing an empty argument list, i.e. zero arguments. You need to pass one argument to `count`.